# Get gdb-readable symbols without -g flag?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, symbols

I'm working on a really big project which I would like to debug with gdb. Unfortunately, compiling with `-g` flag takes two days and a half and output libraries that are larger than 60Go (project takes ~1Go without  `-g`).

is there a simpler way to obtain a symbols table (i.e. be able to backtrace) and if yes, how ?
I've seen that gdb offers three levels of debugging (-g *level* as described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC9)), would it help ? Would `string` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "Would `string`?"

Comment: I found this switch `-feliminate-unused-debug-symbols` which seems to shrink one of my lib from 800Mo to 35Mo (original 8Mo). I'll let it work overnight on the entire project, and will let you know about the results.

Comment: @aix : Someone told me that it would be possible to use the `string` command to parse my objects.
@RicardoCárdenes : Thanks ! I'll try that if my try below doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a backtrace with just function names, you don't need `-g` at all.

For a backtrace with file and line info, using recent GCC versions, try `-gmlt` option (minimal line table). Note that no local variable info will be available in GDB.

If you want local variables, you'll probably want to use `-gdwarf-4`.

The documentation you pointed at is for `gcc-2.95`. That is an *ancient* version. If you are still using it, your *first* task should be to switch to (current) `gcc-4.6.2`

Comment: I used `-ggdb` coupled with `-feliminate-unused-debug-symbols` and it works for me. I'll try `-gmlt` though, it could work and use less disk space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea about source files you want to debug `compile them with -g option`. Make sure you `link with -g` option too. Now you have a partial debug image.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to be able to debug the entire application.